# What is XOR Equivalence

Tags: computer-science, logical-operators, cpu-architecture, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to see the equivalence of the XOR expression but I cannot. I am trying to express a XOR with only NANDs

```
 A^B
=AB'+A'B
=(A+B)(AB)'           <= This the transformation I don't understand.
=((A(AB)')'(B(AB)')')'
```

Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Which exactly ? From line 2 to line 3 or from line 3 to line 4 ?

Comment: Follow the signal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go backwards with more steps

`(A+B)(AB)'`

`<=>A(AB)' + B(AB)'`   (distributivity)

`<=>A(A'+B') + B(A'+B')` (demorgan on `(AB)'`)

`<=>AA' + AB' + BA' + BB'`  (distributivity)

Since `AA'` and `BB'` evaluate to false (i.e. T AND F or F AND T result in False), they can be removed from the chained or-condition leaving (False OR X <=> X)

`AB' + A'B`

---

So back to the original . . .

1) they start with the `AB' + A'B`

2) added the terms `AA'` and `BB'` giving `AA' + AB' + BA' + BB'`

3) factored out `(A'+B')` leaving `A(A' + B') + B(A' + B')`

4) Rearranged to `(A+B)(A'+B')`

4) Finally demogran law to result in `(A+B)(AB)'`

Comment: Great explanation. Basically a few terms where added so we could group. :)